# How to pass in a body of array in React axios and accept a body of array data in Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I have a post request in the server that needs to accept an array of body to use InsertMany in mongoose.

The model is called order and is meant to store an array of products name per order. I currently have in the server a sample

```
const data = [ 
                {name: 'Phone'},
                {name: 'Guitar'},
             ]

let order = await Order.insertMany(data)
```

So now, I'm looking to find how it'll be in the client with axios

Answer (score 3):

dont know if I got your question, but if the problem is in your axios request, just add it on your default axios package payload:

```
import axios from 'axios';

let payload = {
  data = [ 
      {name: 'Phone'},
      {name: 'Guitar'},
  ]
};

axios({
  url: 'your_url',
  method: 'post',
  data: payload
})
.then(function (response) {
    // your action after success
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
   // your action on error success
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: on the server you would do something like that
`const data = req.body.data` , if you follow above technique to send the data to api.